# Java Comparator Sort Differently

Tags: java, string, comparator

public class StringComparatorTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"abc9", "abc", "abc123", "ab9"};
    String[] b = {"abc9", "abc", "abc123", "ab9"};
    String[] c = {"abc9", "abc", "abc123", "ab9"};

    System.out.print("a_Origin     : ");
    printArray(a);
    System.out.print("c_Origin     : ");
    printArray(c);

    System.out.print("a_Default    : ");
    Arrays.sort(a);
    printArray(a);

    System.out.print("c_Default    : ");
    Arrays.sort(c);
    printArray(c);

    System.out.print("a_Customized1: ");
    Arrays.sort(a, new StringComparator());
    printArray(a);

    System.out.print("b_Customized1: ");
    Arrays.sort(b, new StringComparator());
    printArray(b);

    System.out.print("c_Customized2: ");
    Arrays.sort(c, new StringComparator2());
    printArray(c);
}

public static void printArray(String[] arr){
    for (String str: arr) {
        System.out.print(str + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

public class StringComparator implements Comparator {

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    if(s1.length() == s2.length()){
        if(s1.equals(s2))
            return 0;
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
                if(s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)){
                    return 1;
                }else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }else if(s1.length() < s2.length()){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

public class StringComparator2 implements Comparator {

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() == s2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (s1.charAt(i) < s2.charAt(i)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

I have to comparators to sort a String objects, it turns out the "StringComparator" has some bugs but I can't figure out.

"StringComparator" works fine at 
"Arrays.sort(b, new StringComparator());"
the out put order is as expected.

but when I use Default sort(steps below) and then sort by "StringComparator", the bug shows:

" Arrays.sort(a);
 Arrays.sort(a, new StringComparator());"

the out put orders are different which should be the same.
(Array a and b are same)

Can someone explain a little bit? 
Thanks a lot~

Comment: hard to believe that is a bug...

Comment: you need to override the compare(Object o1, Object o2).    `@Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return compare((String)o1, (String)o2);
    }`

Comment: Are you attempting to implement standard lexagraphical sorting? You aren't. You're sorting by length of string and then alphabetically when the lengths are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works - compare in StringComparator class -

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.length() == s2.length()){
            if(s1.equals(s2))
                return 0;
            else{
                for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
                    if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
                        return s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
```

The result given for an array which is sorted first with default sort and then custom comparator(a_customized) is same as the on with using the custom comparator (b_customized)

The issue in old code seems to be here -

```
 if(s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)){
    return 1;
 }else {
    return -1;
 }
```

if the s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i) then also it was returning -1;

Comment: Thank you I found the problem